# error #301 in SyncClient desktop and mobile for OwnCloud

Tags: networking, synchronization, owncloud, softaculous

I've installed OwnCloud on my web hosting (webhostingHub) via Softaculous Auto Installer (i.e. on my hosting cPanel). Web access is working fine.

However,When I try to sync via the desktop clientSync I receive the following error:

"Local sync folder /Users/...../ownCloud already exists, setting it up for sync.

Remote folder clientsync creation failed with error 301.
Connection to ownCloud could not be established. Please check again."

I've searched online but all is dead end.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after intensive research. I found this explanation:

"The remote folder clientsync creation looks like it failed because you're trying to create a folder using webDAV - which will not work on a Shared Server account (any Business level account). You should be able to make this folder mount on your desktop system, but not with the web hosting server. You can make this service work on a VPS or Dedicated server account, but unfortunately not on the your current level of account."

http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/community-support/website/owncloud-sync-issues

Good luck!